# Azure DevOps - basic script - echo commands failed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

```yaml
variables:
    yamlvar : "I'm YAML Variable"
    group : DevGroup

stages:
  - stage: DevStage
    jobs:
     - job: 2019Job
       steps:
        - script: |
          displayName: step 1
           echo $(yamlvar)
           echo $(inputvar)
           echo $(SirisJob)
```

I started practicing the YAML. Not Sure why this code is failing to run.

- yamlvar - Initialized in the same YAML code.
- Inputvar - given at run section.
- Sirisjob - this variable is from the variable group saved in library.

**Error**: `Stage DevStage job 2019Job has an invalid name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs: [jobs.job definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines)

> job string. Required as first property. ID of the job. Acceptable
> values: Valid names may only contain alphanumeric characters and '_'
> and may not start with a number.