# Azure DevOps - basic script - echo commands failing in syntax

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

```yaml
variables:
    yamlvar : "I'm YAML Variable"
    group : DevGroup

stages:
  - stage: DevStage
    jobs:
     - job: _2019Job
       steps:
        - script: |
           echo $(yamlvar)
           echo $(inputvar)
           echo $(VanisJob)
          displayName: Step1
          name: StepName1
```

Not able to find where I did wrong in the above YAML code, it is throwing me the below error:

```
line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.
```

Comment: Macro syntax `$()` inserts the value directly into the script with no escaping. Variables can be enclosed in quotation marks, so the quotation marks do not appear in the script. You should use environment variables, mapped into the script via an `env` block. What you've written is equivalent to writing `echo I'm YAML Variable`, and it's failing due to the single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the double quote `echo "$(yamlvar)"` to avoid the avoid failure due to the single quote in `$(yamlvar)`.

At the same time, according to [Use a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group), if you use both variables and variable groups, use the `name`/`value` syntax for the individual non-grouped variables.

So I changed the yaml code as the following one and it works. (I refer to the variable definition you posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77800159/azure-devops-basic-script-echo-commands-failed).)

```
variables:
- name: yamlvar
  value: "I'm YAML Variable"
- group : DevGroup

stages:
  - stage: DevStage
    jobs:
     - job: _2019Job
       steps:
        - script: |
           echo "$(yamlvar)"
           echo $(inputvar)
           echo $(VanisJob)
          displayName: Step1
          name: StepName1
```

Input:

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]